# TASK_WRITE_FAILED Task failed while writing rows to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm running an insert statement using Databricks SQL:

```
INSERT INTO my_catalog.my_schema.my_table (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c FROM [...];
```

and I'm getting the error message:

```
[TASK_WRITE_FAILED] Task failed while writing rows to 
s3://my_bucket/my_catalog/__unitystorage/catalogs/123456/tables/123456.
```

which doesn't help much on understanding the failure reason: it seems related to S3 but other insert statements in the same Catalog (even in the same schema) work just fine.

Any tips on what this might be related to? Also would be nice to have more meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I tried adding a `LIMIT` to the SQL query in order to process less records and I started getting a different error, related to casting and it was something like:

```
[CAST_OVERFLOW_IN_TABLE_INSERT] Fail to insert a value of "DECIMAL(10, 0)" type into the "DECIMAL(32, 16)" type column `a` due to an overflow. 
Use `try_cast` on the input value to tolerate overflow and return NULL instead.
```

Afterwards I recreated the destination table based on the original `INSERT` statement and it started working even without the `LIMIT` clause.

I feel like `TASK_WRITE_FAILED` was hiding the real underlying error and with the `LIMIT` clause the real error will then show up.

**TLDR**: The initial error message wasn't helpful to understand what was the real problem, adding `LIMIT` to my query unblocked me and took me to understand it.

I hope this can be improved.